# Django not show images

Tags: python, django, django-media

Pls tell me. Why `../static/image.jpg` show images, and `../media/image.jpg` now show

Need write url? Need change Setting? i dont fiend answer in documentation.

pls help.

2 night search answer.

Need upload from admin-panel photo and show in templates.

```
<img src="{{ tovar.product_img.url }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

To display image you need load the static files in your template before referencing them. This is how you should display a picture in your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static 'image.jpg' %}">
```

This image needs to be stored in your static folder. `../YourApp/YourApp/static/image.jpg` is where I keep my static folder. Obviously it would be better to structure it further with images folder inside the static folder etc..

In your settings file you need the following lines:

```
# Static asset configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Then why don't you move your media folder inside the static files folder or create a similar variable to reference your media folder?

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/yourmediafolder/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # whatever but it should same in `urls.py`
```

In `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Then in `template`

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/imagename.jpg"/>
```

**Note:** Here `image` should be as `'/path/to/yourmediafolder/images/imagename.jpg'`

**Complete example:**

I have an image `test.jpg` as `'/home/me/test.jpg`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/' # or /home/me/ but change url in image src
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#urls.py same as above
```

In `template`

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}me/test.jpg"/> # or <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}test.jpg"/> as or condition above in MEDIA_ROOT.
```

**Note that** `{{ MEDIA_URL }}me` , no `/` between them because `MEDIA_URL='/media/`

You can test by:

```
http://domain.com/media/me/test.jpg # or  http://domain.com/media/test.jpg as OR condition in MEDIA_ROOT
```

in local:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/me/test.jpg #in locally
```

Comment: if i used localhost. How link in MEDIA_ROOT need use?

Comment: no matter what `env`. put abs path something like `/var/myimages/`

Comment: If my MEDIA_URL is '/media/', and abs path to 'media' folder is 'D:/project_django/project1/media', will MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/project_django/project1/media' ? And if my upload_to = 'img' (in models), will my uploaded files be pushed to folder 'media/img'?? And then could I write in template <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}media/img/imagename.jpg" />

Comment: And what exactly imagename.jpg is? Is it an abstract name for any .jpg picture or is it a concrete name of my picture? And what if I load another picture to ImageField of another object of my Class with ImageField? How does Django uderstand which picture from 'media/img' to display in template? Wouldn't I change my code every time I load a new picture?

Comment: I explained an example how url and root to be set.Then one thing you have to note that 'only image name and path is saved in database`(others also).So you have to query all imagenames from models and can apply this inside a for loop.

Comment: Oh, I cant understand.. If my folder 'images' with test.jpg (just as your folder 'me' with test.jpg) is in folder 'project1' which is env, what my MEDIA_ROOT must be equal to?

Comment: Then `MEDIA_ROOT='/path/to/images/'`, `MEDIA_URL='/media/'` , `src={{MEDIA_URL}}test.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

This works (in the html img tag):
    src="(left squiggly, percent) static poc.image.name (percent, right squiggly):

...and thanks to whoever pointed out that ImageField has a name in addition to a (useless) path and (useless) url e.g.:

```
>>> from nutr.models import *
>>> poc=POC.objects.get(pk=87)
>>> poc.name
```

'Edgar'

Comment: Sorry, it won't take html.

Answer (score 0):

In `Django==2.0.2` use `{% get_media_prefix %}`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix)